# I am trying to write a SQL Server query using joins and having some difficulty

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tables are explained in detail as below:

I have 3 tables:

**Table A**:
It serves as the master table for information about the employees.

- EmployeeId(Primary key)
- Employee Designation
- EmployeeName (More columns of employee data which is not relevant to this particular query)

**Table B**:
It serves as table where all employees who are accounted for are stored. For ex an employee who has reported sick or is on leave or has pregnancy leave, etc. Bottom line an employee which is not available

- EmployeeID (primary key) (also referencing master table A as foreign key)
- AccountedFor
- AccountedFordurationFrom (datetime)
- AccountedForDurationTo (datetime)

**Table C:**
It serves as a table where excused data of employees are present. For ex we have our organization's time table spread as events, 1st event is morning time conference, then 2nd is silence working time, 3rd is brainstorming sessions etc. Now if an employee is excused for a particular event, it is entered here.

- EmployeeID
- EventCode
- Excuse_DurationFrom
- Excuse Duration To
- Any specific details

Here `EmployeeID` and `ExcusedForEventCode` are both composite primary keys as it is possible to have same `employeeId` for multiple excuses,but the combination is always unique.

We have built some custom attendance management system and would require the following details:

1. We need to find all those employees who are neither accounted for nor excused for a specific event(this will be provided through front end) for a time duration selected through the front end.
2. The result of the above query will subsequently be used to compare with a biometric attendance machine logs which gives 
   `EmployeeId|LogDate(datetime)|EventCodes` as a separate table input to our database (Master table A employeeId references this EmployeeId as foreign key)

It will be compared to find out true absentees for a particular event. ie All those employees who are neither accounted for, nor excuses for any particular event and who does not figure out in the biometric scan machine logs are absented for those time duration selected. We need the output of absentee like this `EmployeeId|Employee Designation|Employee Name|EventName (have a separate table linking with EventCode)|Date&time` (this would be per day per event report of employee who are absent from the selected time duration).

We have tried queries like:

```
select 
    employeemastertable.employeeid, 
    employeemastertable.Designation,
    employeemastertable.Name,
    EventCodes.EventCodeName as Eventexcusedfrom 
from 
    employeemastertable 
inner join 
    employeeexcusedforevents on employeemastertable.employeeid = employeeexcusedforevents.employeeid 
inner join 
    EventCodes on employeeexcusedforEvents.ExcusedForEventCode = EventCodes.Eventcode 
left join 
    employeeaccountedFor on employeemastertable.employeeid = employeeaccountedFor.employeeid 
where 
    employeeexcusedforevents.ExcusedForEventCode != 1 (Morning conference) 
    and employeeaccountedFor.employeeid is null;
```

Names have been changed

I do understand this will give those employees who does not figure out in event Morning conference but even if I do left join instead of inner join between employeemastertable and employeeexcusedForevents and put employeeexcusedforevents.excusedforeventcode is null and employeeexcusedforevents.employeeid is null, I do get all those employees not present in the other two table, but the criteria of event is not satisfied. That means what if the employee is excused for the 2nd event as well in the organization. How would I cater for that in the above code? (PS this is only the 1st part of the equation I understand that, after this I need help for the other part also, where time duration and comparing with logs is concerned)?

Comment: Why is it given negative rating?Can anybody explain?I have explained my question in detail,specially showing the effort i have made

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is wrong about the results from this query? Are there too many rows selected? Too few? Any wrong rows?

Comment: As general advice: I recommend using SELECT DISTINCT, make sure you include any other needed comparisons in the ON statement for each join (such as date ranges), and instead of using the final LEFT JOIN, I would recommend taking that out and adding a NOT EXISTS check to the WHERE clause. These steps can help narrow down to the expected results.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions. (This is the reason for my downvote, and might be the cause of the other one too).

Comment: I do understand it now brother, thank you for the wisdom

Answer (score 0):

I assume there will be just one row for the EventCode=1 in table EventCodes. Below I cross join the wanted event to the employee master table and then exclude any employees that are excused or accounted for.

```
-- employees neither accounted for nor excused for a specific event
SELECT
      em.employeeid
    , em.Designation
    , em.Name
    , ec.EventCodeName AS Eventexcusedfrom
FROM employeemastertable em
CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT Eventcode, EventCodeName
      FROM EventCodes
      WHERE Eventcode = 1
      ) ec
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT NULL
      FROM employeeexcusedforevents ee
      WHERE em.employeeid = ee.employeeid
      AND ec.Eventcode = ee.ExcusedForEventCode
      )
AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT NULL
      FROM employeeaccountedFor eaf
      WHERE em.employeeid = eaf.employeeid
      )
;
```